# How to Add columns to a current range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there any example of excel VBA that adds 2 columns to the current range then insert data in those columns.
Thank you.

Comment: Using the macro recorder will give you some rudimentary code that can be edited to suit your requirements.

Comment: I think you are looking for `Offset`.

Comment: @ReyJuna any example plz?!

Answer (score 1):

An easy example based on the dimensions of the original set of data:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range, rNew As Range, rCombined As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long, nFirstRow As Long
    Dim nLastColumn As Long, nFirstColumn As Long

    Set r = Range("B2:D7")

    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    nFirstRow = r.Row
    nFirstColumn = r.Column

    Set rNew = Range(Cells(nFirstRow, nLastColumn + 1), Cells(nLastRow, nLastColumn + 2))
    Set rCombined = Union(r, rNew)

    r.Value = "x"
    rNew.Value = "y"
    MsgBox rCombined.Address

End Sub
```

[image]